# Errors on functioning Applications

Tags: php, html

I have created a contact form which I was able to get functioning on my website however, I have also created a second form on my website on a different page which plays its role as an application form.

What I have done was take the functioning contact form and copy and paste it on to this application form and just add more fields on both HTML and PHP.

However, the form does not submit the information to the email which is weird because the contact form does and they are both the exact same thing... only difference is more fields.

I have looked at what the cause may be but I can't seem to spot it... is there a specific function I should be adding if I have two forms on the same website but different pages?

I have looked into a code error checker that I ran across on Google and it seems to say that there is something wrong on the input line on HTML. I did the same for my contact form but it seems okay. I don't understand why it would possibly say that if they are the same thing.

On the HTML `name="example_1"` field I have added underscores but have used the same exact thing on PHP. Is that something that is even allowed in PHP?

I also want to mention that the form doesn't have a subject or message field as there is no need for one. Does every PHP file require that for a form?

Excuse my amateur questions but this is all quite new to me and I can't seem to find the root of my mess. I hope we can work out the root of the error together.

I have added the coding to make things easier to understand what I'm saying.

```css
<?php
session_start();
if( isset($_POST['name']) && strtoupper($_POST['captcha']) == $_SESSION['captcha_id'] )
{
 $to = 'mytestgmail@gmail.com'; // Replace with your email 
 $subject = 'You have a new application!'; // Replace with your $subject
 $headers = 'From: ' . 'mygmail@gmail.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email_address']; 
 
 $message = 'Full Name: ' . $_POST['full_name'] . "\n" .
      'Date of Birth: ' . $_POST['dob'] . "\n" .
      'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email_address'] . "\n" .
      'Contact: ' . $_POST['contact_number'] . "\n" .
      'Address: ' . $_POST['home_address'] . "\n" .
      'Make: ' . $_POST['make'] . "\n" .
      'Model: ' . $_POST['model'] . "\n" .
      'Registration: ' . $_POST['reg'] . "\n" .
      'ID: ' . $_POST['id'] . "\n" . "\n" .

      'TP Full Name: ' . $_POST['tp_full_name'] . "\n" .
      'TP Date of Birth: ' . $_POST['tp_dob'] . "\n" .
      'TP E-mail: ' . $_POST['tp_email_address'] . "\n" .
      'TP Contact No.: ' . $_POST['tp_contact_number'] . "\n" .
      'TP Address: ' . $_POST['tp_home_address'] . "\n" .
      'TP Make: ' . $_POST['tp_make'] . "\n" .
      'TP Model: ' . $_POST['tp_model'] . "\n" .
      'TP Registration: ' . $_POST['tp_reg'] . "\n" .
      'TP ID: ' . $_POST['tp_id'] . "\n" . "\n" .
            'Source: ' . $_POST['source'];
 
 mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
 if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
 {
  mail($_POST['email_address'], $subject, $message, $headers);
 }
}
?>
```

```html
          <form action="claims-process.php" method="post" id="sky-form" class="sky-form sty-one" novalidate>
            <fieldset class="sty-one">
              <br>
              <br>
              <h5 class="uppercase">Your Details</h5>
              <br>
              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">Full Name</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="name" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">Date of Birth</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input name="dob" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              
              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">E-mail</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <input name="email_address" id="name" type="email">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">Contact Number</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <input name="contact_number" id="name" type="number" minlength="11" maxlength="13">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              <section>
                <label class="label">Address</label>
                <label class="textarea">
                  <i class="icon-append fa fa-home"></i>
                  <textarea rows="4" name="home_address" id="name"></textarea>
                </label>
              </section>

              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">Make</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-car"></i>
                    <input name="make" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">Model</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-car"></i>
                    <input name="model" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">Registration</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-car"></i>
                    <input name="reg" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">ID</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-shield"></i>
                    <input name="id" id="name" type="text" minlength="11" maxlength="13">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>   
              <br>
              <br>
              <h5 class="uppercase">TP</h5>
              <br>
              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP Full Name</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-user"></i>
                    <input name="tp_full_name" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP Date of Birth</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    <input name="tp_dob" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              
              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP E-mail</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <input name="tp_email_address" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP Contact Number</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <input name="tp_contact_number" id="name" type="number" minlength="11" maxlength="13">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>

              <section>
                <label class="label">TP Address</label>
                <label class="textarea">
                  <i class="icon-append fa fa-home"></i>
                  <textarea rows="4" name="tp_home_address" id="name"></textarea>
                </label>
              </section>

              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP Make</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-car"></i>
                    <input name="tp_make" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP Model</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-car"></i>
                    <input name="tp_model" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP Registration</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-car"></i>
                    <input name="tp_reg" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
                <section class="col col-6">
                  <label class="label">TP ID</label>
                  <label class="input">
                    <i class="icon-append fa fa-shield"></i>
                    <input name="tp_id" id="name" type="text">
                  </label>
                </section>
              </div>              
              <section>
                <label class="label">Source</label>
                <label class="input">
                  <i class="icon-append fa fa-tag"></i>
                  <input name="source" id="subject" id="name" type="text">
                </label>
              </section>

              <section>
                <label class="label">Enter characters below:</label>
                <label class="input input-captcha">
                  <img src="captcha/image.php?<?php echo time(); ?>" alt="Captcha image" width="100" height="35">
                  <input maxlength="6" name="captcha" id="captcha" type="text">
                </label>
              </section>
              
              <section>
                <label class="checkbox"><input name="copy" type="checkbox"><i></i>Send a copy to my e-mail address</label>
              </section>
            </fieldset>
            <footer>
              <button type="submit" name="submit" class="button">Submit Claim</button>
            </footer>
      <div class="message">
       <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
       <p>Your message was successfully sent!</p>
      </div>
     </form>
```

Comment: Your form and mail script works for me, possibly you have some other issue going on. Where does it actually get to? does it get past the `if` clause?

Comment: How would I be able to check?

Comment: After the `if` line, just do `die(print_r($_POST));`. See if it stops there and prints the post array. If it does make it, check the data is right.

Comment: You also need to use `filter_var()` to verify that the email is valid. `mail()` can be manipulated by a skilled user to send spam, and even if it’s not a public-facing feature, you should secure it.

Comment: And it should be `die(print_r($_POST,1));`

Comment: I've added 'die(print_r($_POST));' under the first 'if' line on the third row. After submitting the form again to test nothing happened... it just went straight to the success page. I didn't get any printing window on Safari. Could it possibly be because there are too many fields since when there are only 4 it works perfectly fine?

Comment: Do before the `if` clause: `print_r([$_POST,$_SESSION]);` and see if the `captcha_id` is set in the session array and that `name` and `captcha` are set in the `$_POST` array.